# MSSOAP30 Object error: 0x80004002: Interface does not exist (VB)

Tags: vba, soap, proxy, toolkit, soap-client

I'm well and truly stuck with MS SOAP 3.0, which I'm currently running from VBA Excel in Office 2003. I have used MS SOAP Toolkit 3 to create a proxy class which I am using. If I don't use it, I don't get the error, but then I'd have to write out the entire proxy class by hand and it's massive.

When my program is first run, I get "Class not registered". If I run it again I get "Interface not supported". The error messge is:

> run-time error: '-2147467262'
>
> SoapMapper: The SoapMapper for element
>   callContextIn could not be created
>   HRESULT=0x80004002: No such interface
>   supported.
>   -WSDLOperation:Initialisation of a SoapMapper for operation getSNFormat
>   HRESULT=0x80004002: No such interfce
>   supported.

The error occurs when:

> Set sc_PartService = New SoapClient30

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just now I deleted "Set", got an error of course, put it back and it ran properly. Once. Not again, and I've been unable to recreate this. Never encountered anything like that before!

Answer (score 0):

HAve you checked if the COM object exists / is registered?

Comment: SoapClient30 exists as a Class in the Object Browser. I'm not sure if that makes it a COM object

Comment: HMm that means it is registered. Could be a security issue of sorts. In administrative tools -> COM -> DCOM config you could see which users have the Local Launch and Local Activation permissions.